# $P(S^2 > 3579)$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, estimation

Suppose

$$\bar{X} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n}{n}$$

and

$$S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2$$

Let $X_1, ... X_{20}$ a sample of size 20 with $N(300, 2500)$

1. The probability that the sample mean is less than $281.61$ is equal to $5$%.
2. The probability that the sample variance is greater than $3579$ is equal to $90$%.

For me, I think only 2 might be true. Intuitively, am I wrong?

I have tried $P(\bar{X} < 281.61) = 1 - \phi(\frac{300-281.61}{\sqrt{2500}}) = 1 - 0.64058 = 0.35942$. So the first choice can't be true. I have no clue where to start with $S^2$.

Comment: An important observation: the probability is not a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following statement (it is not difficult to prove it)

$$\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi_{(n-1)}^2$$

But the correct statement is the first.

$$\mathbb{P}[\overline{X}_{20}<281.61]=\mathbb{P}\Big[Z<\frac{281.61-300}{50}\sqrt{20}\Big]=\Phi(-1.64485)=0.05=5\%$$

The second statement is

$$\mathbb{P}[S^2>3579]=\mathbb{P}\Bigg[\chi_{(19)}^2>\frac{3579\times 19}{2500}\Bigg]=0.1=10\%$$

The first result has been derived using Z-table, the second using $\chi^2$ table

Comment: I did not learn the chi law $\chi_{(n-1)}^2$ yet. Can you propose an easier way of doing it?

Comment: J.Doe : added the solution. The correct statement is the first you marked incorrect. Your error was in deriving st deviaton of $\overline{X}_{20}$

Comment: I have not seen the chi law. Can you propose a standard way of doing it?

Comment: @J.Doe : unfortunately for you, probabilities of $S^2$ in a Gaussian model should be solved with $S^2$ distribution...that is a chi squared. I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Comment: Suppose you just don't know the chi law at the beginning. Would you be able to find the law describing $S^2$?It is just because I have not seen the chi law yet. At the beginning. I thought about finding the distribution of $S^2$, but I was not able to do so. Can you please explain where $\sqrt{20}$ comes from?